# If salary of employee is up to 5000 then rank =1, up to 100k then rank = 2 and so on. can we get the result using rank function?

Tags: sql-server, ranking-functions

If salary of employee is below 50,000 then rank = 1, up to 100 000 then rank 2, up to 150 000 then rank 3.Can I get this using rank function?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SALARY BETWEEN 1 , 50000 then 1 
else case when salary between 50000 , 100000 then 2
else case when salary between 150000 , 200000 then 3 else 4 end as rank FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP = 1
```

Comment: Your logic is correct, but your syntax is slightly off.

Comment: @stickybit, his use of `BETWEEN` seems legitimate here - the case of 50,000.50 will be ranked as 2, in proper accordance with the logic.

Comment: @Steve: Ah yeah, you're right, I was wrong.

Comment: you most probably want to use ntile function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924591/how-can-i-group-student-scores-into-quintile-using-sql-server-2008 .

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it seems that you just need a way to calculate the rank for intervals of `50,000`, so you don't have to use successive `CASE` expressions. This can be done easily enough using simple integer division, rather than the `RANK` function:

```
SELECT *, CAST(salary / 50000 AS INT) + 1 AS Rnk
FROM Employee
```

gives you these results:

```
+-----+-----------+-----+
| emp |  salary   | rnk |
+-----+-----------+-----+
|   1 |  49000.00 |   1 |
|   2 |  50000.00 |   2 |
|   3 |  99000.00 |   2 |
|   4 | 100000.00 |   3 |
|   5 | 149000.00 |   3 |
|   6 | 150000.00 |   4 |
+-----+-----------+-----+
```

If desired, you could also add this as a calculated column (and index it) as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect, there is how `CASE` should be used:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN salary BETWEEN 1 AND 49999 THEN 1 
        WHEN salary BETWEEN 50000 AND 99999 THEN 2
        WHEN salary BETWEEN 100000 AND 150000 THEN 3 
        ELSE 4 
    END AS rnk 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE EMP = 1 -- I'm not sure what you trying to filter here
```

Comment: i wanted to know if i can replace the case function using rank function

Comment: @manojsaisuryasrikanta why do you need to replace it? `RANK` should be used for other purposes.

Comment: if i have to calculate the rnk for salary up to 800000 then i have to write 16 case statements. so, i wanted to make it simple. please suggest if there is any other way around

Comment: For ranking you don't defined the cutoff. It is rather to divide the records in groups by say top quieter, two medium and bottom. Better you use a defined cutoff